# How can you display textbox1 value in textbox2 using keystokes

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have 2 textbox (textbox 1 & textbox 2 ); the textbox1 has numeric value such as $1,000. Now when i am in textbox2 and if i hit keystrokes like (= or + or pageup or pagedown etc...) the textbox1 value should appear in textbox2.

The reason behind this is to enable customers improve speed in processsing/ filling data.

Comment: what is the problem? Cant you use any of keydown/up/pressed events?

Comment: Handle it in keypress event, simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand what you need, anyway try this:

```
private void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.PageDown ||
        e.KeyCode == Keys.PageUp ||
        e.KeyCode == Keys.Oemplus ||
        e.KeyCode == Keys.Add ||
        (e.KeyCode == Keys.D0 && e.Shift))
    {
        textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text;
        e.Handled = true;
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mr.Info: try my edited answer, it's a little more complete now

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a keyPress event on textbox2 with a function like this:

```
    private void textbox2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == '+')
        {
            textbox2.Text = textbox1.Text;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
protected void textbox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(textbox2.Text=="+"||textbox2.Text=="=")
  textbox2.Text=textbox1.Text;
}
```

Comment: and text in textbox2 will contain '+' or '=' symbols